# While/ for loop until specific condition appear

Tags: c#

I'm using specific code:

```
    while (!productsPage.FiltersComponent.TableComponent.CheckIfFilterResultsValid("Product Name", TableComparares.Exact, stockSimpleName))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            productsPage.FiltersComponent.DeleteSpecificFilterChip(stockSimpleName);
            productsPage.FiltersComponent.UseStringFilter(FiltersOptions.ProductName, stockSimpleName);

            if (i == 3) Assert.Fail("Product was not possible of being found after importing, tried three times");
        }
    }
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm loading a new file, then I filter it by the table filter mechanism until row (file) will appear inside the table. As the queue is sometimes short/ sometimes fast it's up to the server how long it will take (most probably those are 3/4 seconds but there are cases when it can take up to even 30 or more sec).

**What are my steps after loading file:**

- Search for that file (product) name by the filter mechanizm
- Check if result appeared inside the table results (while loop)
- Delete the filter (retake an action)
- Retry the action up to three times
- Assert.Fail which means that file was not loaded correctly

Right now when product is not found for the first time and code get's into the while/ for loop then it will go into infinitive loop until it find the product which is not good.

Comment: A well defined, scoped question with the actual code already in there, including what you want, what you tried good example on how to ask a question.

Comment: Your `Assert.Fail` won't never be called. the IF Condition should be `i == 2`.

Comment: Riiight ok...but anyway I'm making mistake somewhere inside for loop. It would be perfect if while condition will be checked each time I delete & usefilter. Right now its done 3 times and then it checks the condition. What I'm trying to achieve is to: Check the while condition maximum three times and after each of those I would like to check the while condition. After third failed check I would like to receive the assert.Fail error.

Comment: Your for-loop is inside the while-loop. So the while-condition is only checked *before* a new for-loop is started, not *during* it. That condition is only re-checked when the for-loop is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close but not quite there yet. Basically you want to try something 3 times and then fail (`for` loop works perfectly fine for that). However as soon as `CheckIfFilterResultsValid` returns `true` you want to stop any future attempts and stop your loop. The keyword `break` is made exactly for that. It breaks out of it's enclosure (`for`, `while`, `switch`). So it would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
  if (i == 3) //check if we're tried 3 times already
    Assert.Fail("Product was not possible of being found after importing, tried three times"); //I assume this will throw an exception, if this does not break the flow you'll also have to add a break here!

  //check if it passes
  if (productsPage.FiltersComponent.TableComponent.CheckIfFilterResultsValid("Product Name", TableComparares.Exact, stockSimpleName))
    break; //this breaks out of the for loop

  //not made 3 attempts yet and not passed our check so do our attempt to fix
  productsPage.FiltersComponent.DeleteSpecificFilterChip(stockSimpleName);
  productsPage.FiltersComponent.UseStringFilter(FiltersOptions.ProductName, stockSimpleName);
}
```

Comment: @Kermi note that the `while` is gone and its condition moved inside the for-loop